# Symfony 2.3 FormType $options inheritance

Tags: php, forms, symfony

tl;dr:
*Is there any way to have the 'context' option auto-cascade through all form types ? It would **NOT** be leasable to pass it along manually in the form types like this:*

```
$builder->add('organizer', 'organizer_type', array('context' => $options['context']));
```

---

Hello everybody,

I have written an extension to ALL Symfony form types:

```
class ContextExtension extends AbstractTypeExtension
{
    protected $context;

    public function __construct(SecurityContextInterface $context)
    {
        $this->context = $context->getToken()->getUser()->getContext();
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'context' => $this->context
        ]);
        $resolver->setAllowedTypes(['context' => 'GOC\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Model\ContextInterface']);
    }

    /**
     * Returns the name of the type being extended.
     *
     * @return string The name of the type being extended
     */
    public function getExtendedType()
    {
        return 'form';
    }
}
```

I have validated that it is registered and working (for the most part). I only face one problem. When I set my new option ('context') in a form type like this:

```
class EventType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add(
            'eventgroup', 'eventgroup_type', array(
                'context' => $context,
            )
        )
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'event';
    }
}
```

I receive the option in the event group form type and can work with it there:

```
class EventGroupType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $this->log($options['context']);

        $builder
            ->add('name', 'text')
            ->add('comment', 'text')
            ->add('organizer', 'organizer_type')
        ;
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'eventgroup_type';
    }
}
```

However, it appears that the options does not cascade any further and is therefore not usable in the text or organizer type. Is there any way to have the 'context' option auto-cascade through all form types ? It would **NOT** be leasable to pass it along manually in the form types like this:

```
$builder->add('organizer', 'organizer_type', array('context' => $options['context']));
```